How to customize the taxonomy terms template?
I am on Drupal 11 and I created a view mode "profile" for taxonomy terms.
I want to customize the template of this view mode for all taxonomy terms.
I named the template as below but it has no effect :
taxonomy-term--profile.html.twig

Taxonomy terms do not use a template whose name contains the view mode, by default; that has been true since Drupal 8. Implementing hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK(), it is possible to suggest more template files to use, as Jaypan already said in his answer.
I would implement it using code similar to the one used by node_theme_suggestions_node().
function mymodule_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];

  /** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $term */
  $term = $variables['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];
  $sanitized_view_mode = strtr($variables['elements']['#view_mode'], '.', '_');
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle();
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->id();
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->id() . '__' . $sanitized_view_mode;

  return $suggestions;
}

As the documentation page says, for taxonomy terms, the suggestions must start with 'taxonomy_term__', or Drupal would not use them. Do not change the suggestions' first characters to, for example, 'taxonomy_term--', or Drupal core will ignore them.

It does not appear that there are view-mode specific handlers added for taxonomy terms. The taxonomy module sets default suggestions in taxonomy_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term() (an implementation of hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK()).
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function taxonomy_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];

  /** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $term */
  $term = $variables['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];

  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle();
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->id();

  return $suggestions;
}

As you can see, suggestions are added for the bundle, and for the ID]s, but not for the view mode.
You will need to implement your own implementation of hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK():
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK().
 */
function HOOK_theme_suggestions_taxonomy_term(array $variables) {
  $suggestions = [];

  /** @var \Drupal\taxonomy\TermInterface $term */
  $term = $variables['elements']['#taxonomy_term'];
  $view_mode = $variables['elements']['#view_mode'];

  // Add a suggestion for the bundle with the view mode.
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $term->bundle() . '__' . $view_mode;
  // Add another suggestion for the view mode on any bundle.
  $suggestions[] = 'taxonomy_term__' . $view_mode;

  return $suggestions;
}

After implementing, clear your cache, and you will be able to use the template name you have provided.
Note that I did not confirm that the view mode is available at $vars['#view_mode'] - you may need to dig around the $vars array with a debugger to find it. I know it's in there somewhere.

Yes, taxonomy terms are handled differently from nodes, which seems rather odd, as they are both entities with view modes.
